# Custom Alert When Checking Data Input, Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, input, alert

I would like to display a custom alert, rather than simply true or false. I have:

```
function isValid(test) {

     return /^[a-zA-Z]{2}(?:\d{6}|\d{8}|\d{10})$/.test(test);
}

function checkValid(){

     var userEntry = document.getElementById("entry1").value;

     alert(isValid(firstRef));

}
```

So depending on whether what the user is valid or not they get the message "true" or "false". I would like the user to get a customised message if their input returns false such as "Invalid format try again" and get no message displayed when they input the correct data. Could I somehow use an if statement along the lines of if true then.... else...?

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work.

Comment: I did try but for some reason couldn't get it to work for me. Probably some silly mistake, not been doing this for that long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function checkValid(){

     var userEntry = document.getElementById("entry1").value;

     if (!isValid(firstRef)) {
         alert("Invalid format try again.");
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your checkValid function to something like this one:

```
function checkValid(){

    var userEntry = document.getElementById("entry1").value;

    if (isValid(firstRef)) {
        alert("It is valid!");
    }
    else {
        alert("It is invalid");
    }
}
```